# Filling a 3D-Body with a systematic point raster

Tags: r, algorithm, 3d

I have a set of 3D-Bodies. Each Body is defined by 8 points with three coordinates each. All of the bodies are cubical or approximately cubical. I would like to "fill" the cubes with a systematic point raster. The coordinates are stored in simple data.frames.

I developed the following code that does what I want for cubical bodies:

```
# libraries
library(rgl)

# define example cube with 8 points
excube <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5), 
  y = c(1,1,4,4,1,1,4,4), 
  z = c(4,8,4,8,4,8,4,8)
)

# cubeconst: fill cube (defined by 8 corner points) with a 3D-point-raster
cubeconst <- function(x, y, z, res) {
  cube <- data.frame()
  xvec = seq(min(x), max(x), res)
  yvec = seq(min(y), max(y), res)
  zvec = seq(min(z), max(z), res)
  for (xpoint in 1:length(xvec)) {
    for (ypoint in 1:length(yvec)) {
      for (zpoint in 1:length(zvec)) {
        cube <- rbind(cube, c(xvec[xpoint], yvec[ypoint], zvec[zpoint]))
      }
    }
  }
  colnames(cube) <- c("x", "y", "z")
  return(cube)
}

# apply cubeconst to excube
fcube <- cubeconst(x = excube$x, y = excube$y, z = excube$z, res = 0.5)

# plot result
plot3d(
  fcube$x,
  fcube$y,
  fcube$z,
  type = "p", 
  xlab = "x", 
  ylab = "y", 
  zlab = "z"
)
```

Now I'm searching for a solution to "fill" approximately cubical bodies like for example the following body:

```
# badcube
badcube <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5), 
  y = c(1,1,4,4,1,1,4,4), 
  z = c(4,10,4,12,4,8,4,8)
)

# plot badcube
plot3d(
  badcube$x,
  badcube$y,
  badcube$z,
  col = "red",
  size = 10,
  type = "p", 
  xlab = "x", 
  ylab = "y", 
  zlab = "z"
)
```

Maybe you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by a "systematic point raster"? I read your question as asking how to divide a distorted cube up into NxNxN smaller cubes. Is this correct?

Comment: @Bill Yes I think you got it. The result of the algorithm should be a list of points which are within the limits of the distorted cube. The points could be randomly distributed, but I would prefer them to be equidistant. The division into NxNxN smaller cubes could be a way to achieve this. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform the hexahedron (wonky cube) to a unit cube. The following image shows what I mean, and gives us a numbering scheme for the vertices of the hexa. Vertex `2` is hidden behind the cube.

[image]

The transformation is from real space `x,y,z`, to a new coordinate system `u,v,w`, in which the hexa is a unit cube. The typical function used for hexa looks like this.

```
x = A + B*u + C*v + D*w + E*u*v + F*u*w + G*v*w + H*u*v*w
```

Transformations for y and z coordinates are of the same form. You have 8 corners to your cube, so you can substitute these in to solve for coefficients `A,B,...`. The unit coordinates `u,v,w` are either `0` or `1` at every vertex, so this simplifies things a lot.

```
x0 = A                             // everything = zero
x1 = A + B                         // u = 1, others = zero
x2 = A + C                         // v = 1, ...
x4 = A + D                         // w = 1
x3 = A + B + C + E                 // u = v = 1
x5 = A + B + D + F                 // u = w = 1
x6 = A + C + D + G                 // v = w = 1
x7 = A + B + C + D + E + F + G + H // everything = 1
```

You then have to solve for `A,B,...`. This is easy because you just forward substitute. `A` equals `x0`. `B` equals `x1 - A`, etc... You have to do this for `y` and `z` also, but if your language supports vector operations, this can probably be done in the same step as for `x`.

Once you have the coefficients, you can convert a point `u,v,w` to `x,y,z`. Now, if you have a point generation scheme which works on a 1x1x1 cube, you can transform the result to the origonal hex. You could retain the same triple-loop structure in your posted code, and vary `u,v,w` between `0` and `1` to create a grid of points within the hex.

I'm afraid I don't know `r`, so I can't give you any example code in that language. Here's a quick `python3` example, though, just to prove it works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

np.random.seed(0)

cube = np.array([
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]])

hexa = cube + 0.5*np.random.random(cube.shape)

edges = np.array([
    [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3],
    [0, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7],
    [4, 5], [4, 6], [5, 7], [6, 7]])

def cubeToHexa(hexa, u, v, w):
    A = hexa[0]
    B = hexa[1] - A
    C = hexa[2] - A
    D = hexa[4] - A
    E = hexa[3] - A - B - C
    F = hexa[5] - A - B - D
    G = hexa[6] - A - C - D
    H = hexa[7] - A - B - C - D - E - F - G
    xyz = (
            A +
            B*u[...,np.newaxis] +
            C*v[...,np.newaxis] +
            D*w[...,np.newaxis] +
            E*u[...,np.newaxis]*v[...,np.newaxis] +
            F*u[...,np.newaxis]*w[...,np.newaxis] +
            G*v[...,np.newaxis]*w[...,np.newaxis] +
            H*u[...,np.newaxis]*v[...,np.newaxis]*w[...,np.newaxis])
    return xyz[...,0], xyz[...,1], xyz[...,2]

fg = pp.figure()
ax = fg.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

temp = np.reshape(np.append(hexa[edges], np.nan*np.ones((12,1,3)), axis=1), (36,3))
ax.plot(temp[:,0], temp[:,1], temp[:,2], 'o-')

u, v, w = np.meshgrid(*[np.linspace(0, 1, 6)]*3)
x, y, z = cubeToHexa(hexa, u, v, w)
ax.plot(x.flatten(), y.flatten(), z.flatten(), 'o')

pp.show()
```

I can't recall the exact justificiation for this form of the transformation. It's certainly easy to solve, and it has no squared terms, so lines in the directions of the `u,v,w` axes map to straight lines in `x,y,z`. This means your cube edges and faces are guaranteed to conform, as well as the corners. I lack the maths to prove it, though, and I couldn't find any googleable information either. My knowledge comes from a distant memory of textbooks on Finite Element Methods, where these sort of transformations are common. If you need more information, I suggest you start looking there.

Comment: Fantastic. It took me two hours to reconstruct this awesome solution in R - but now it works. Thanks a lot! Tomorrow I'll clean up the resulting R function and post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Bills explanation and examples I was able to come up with the following solution in R:

```
# libraries
library(rgl)

# create heavily distorted cube - hexahedron
hexatest <- data.frame(
  x = c(0,1,0,4,5,5,5,5), 
  y = c(1,1,4,4,1,1,4,4), 
  z = c(4,8,4,9,4,8,4,6)
)

# cubetohexa: Fills hexahedrons with a systematic point raster
cubetohexa <- function(hexa, res){

  # create new coordinate system (u,v,w)
  resvec <- seq(0, 1, res)
  lres <- length(resvec)

  u <- c()
  for (p1 in 1:lres) {
    u2 <- c()
    for (p2 in 1:lres) {
      u2 <- c(u2, rep(resvec[p2], lres))
    }
    u <- c(u,u2)
  }

  v <- c()
  for (p1 in 1:lres) {
    v <- c(v, rep(resvec[p1], lres^2))
  }

  w <- rep(resvec, lres^2)

  # transformation
  A <- as.numeric(hexa[1,])
  B <- as.numeric(hexa[2,]) - A
  C <- as.numeric(hexa[3,]) - A
  D <- as.numeric(hexa[5,]) - A
  E <- as.numeric(hexa[4,]) - A - B - C
  F <- as.numeric(hexa[6,]) - A - B - D
  G <- as.numeric(hexa[7,]) - A - C - D
  H <- as.numeric(hexa[8,]) - A - B - C - D - E - F - G

  A <- matrix(A, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)
  B <- matrix(B, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)
  C <- matrix(C, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)
  D <- matrix(D, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)
  E <- matrix(E, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)
  F <- matrix(F, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)
  G <- matrix(G, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)
  H <- matrix(H, ncol = 3, nrow = lres^3, byrow = TRUE)

  for (i in 1:(lres^3)) {
    B[i,] <- B[i,] * u[i]
    C[i,] <- C[i,] * v[i]
    D[i,] <- D[i,] * w[i]
    E[i,] <- E[i,] * u[i] * v[i]
    F[i,] <- F[i,] * u[i] * w[i]
    G[i,] <- G[i,] * v[i] * w[i]
    H[i,] <- H[i,] * u[i] * v[i] * w[i]
  }

  m <- data.frame(A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H)
  colnames(m) <- c("x", "y", "z")

  # output
  return(m)
}

# apply cubetohexa to hexatest
cx <- cubetohexa(hexatest, 0.1)

# plot result
plot3d(
  cx$x,
  cx$y,
  cx$z,
  type = "p", 
  xlab = "x", 
  ylab = "y", 
  zlab = "z"
)
```

---

**Edit:**

This function is now implemented with Rcpp in my R package [recexcavAAR](https://github.com/ISAAKiel/recexcavAAR).